# Highlander in the World of Darkness using Geist

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, geist-the-sin-eaters

I'm a big fan of Highlander, and somehow the idea of immortals who run around cutting off each others heads seems to fit in the strange World of Darkness. I was thinking about it, and it occurred to me that you might be able to have geists that do this — consume the spirits of other Geists somehow. However, I only flipped through the *Geist* book a few years back when it first came out. I know that the spirit they bargain will bring them back from the brink. What I'm not sure is if consuming another's spirit would be possible or whether they could halt aging. Would such a thing be possible?

*update* I should say that Geist is just a thought on my part, a suggested solution, rather than a necessarily desired solution.

Comment: There's an immortal tied to a place of power in WoD: Immortals http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/14/14301.phtml which might fit the bill a little better than Geist with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I am admittedly unfamiliar with *Geist* there is actually a decent set of homebrew rules for Highlander characters in 2nd and 3rd edition World of Darkness.

*Highlander: The Gathering,* often referred to as H:TG, is a net.supplement which incorporates Highlander-style Immortals into White Wolf's World of Darkness. It was first released by Hank Driskill in September 1993, and a Second Edition, developed by John Gavigan in conjunction with Hank, was published in June 1994.

The second edition version of the rules are available [here](http://vampirerpg.free.fr/Rules/Highlander/) and a recent revised [3rd edition pdf](http://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com/pdf/Misc/Immortal_Rules_Revised.pdf) and character sheets courtesy of [Mr Gone.](http://mrgone.rocksolidshells.com/)

Hopefully even if the rule sets are not entirely usable those will be good starting points to help design characters.

Comment: Even though this A doesn't concern itself with Geist, which seems to have been an important part of the Q, I think its offering an already existing alternative is not a bad thing at all, so +1 from me. (Also, it brings back memories, of all the numerous attempts at Highlander conversions one'd come across back in the old days, both online and offline. Come to think of it, it's kinda strange I've never actually given a try to any of them.)